# vscode is not respecting editor.quickSuggestions settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode, I have the following settings:

```
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": true,
    "strings": true
  },
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "other": true,
      "comments": true,
      "strings": true
    },
```

I am debugging [this issue](https://github.com/kortina/vscode-markdown-notes/issues/1) for plugin [Markdown Notes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kortina.vscode-markdown-notes).

I believe at some point the settings value for `editor.quickSuggestions` changed from a boolean to the new mapping. In any case, in a document I have the text:

```
#draft
#d
```

And this used to autocomplete the tag text immediately, respecting the `quickSuggestions` preference.

Now, I don't get an automatic autocomplete, BUT I DO get the correct autocomplete values when I `triggerSuggest` (`⌃Space` by default).

So vscode DOES know the correct completion values, but it just will not respect the `quickSuggestions` setting.

Is there some other new setting I need to toggle to get `quickSuggestions` working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have

```
{
  "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true
}
```

set to `false`?