# Disable VSCode autocomplete curly braces

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Lately I'm having issues with the vscode autocomplete .

It basically disables the autocomplete after hitting enter and I have to hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for the autocomplete to appear and select one like this :

[image: vscode-autocomplete]

The behavior I expect is after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> When I begin to type , the autocomplete appears and checks my typing to find the best thing I want to select .

How can I enable autocomplete after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> while I type in vscode ?

Comment: @martijn I'm not sure why this was closed as a dup of [Intellisense not working in code snippets - VS Code](/q/55683145). The icon in the gif is not the one for snippets. It looks to be [the one for fields](/a/57679985).

Comment: @user there was an answer here copied from that post that had been accepted. Since the OP had accepted the answer we converted that to a duplicate closure. See it like a duplicate suggestion accepted by the OP.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah ok. Now I'm just confused why my answer here got accepted. The asker's comments there say it didn't work for them :P. Guess I might never know. (not that I'm complaining)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `editor.quickSuggestions` solve your problem?

[The VS Code docs state](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings):

```json
// Controls whether suggestions should automatically show up while typing.
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": "on",
  "comments": "off",
  "strings": "off"
},

// Controls the delay in milliseconds after which quick suggestions will show up.
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,
```

It might also be worth checking if you have `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters` set to `false` and see if behaviour changes when toggled. Trigger characters are characters like `.`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no I don't know why it works ok when I type ```style``` and press ```Enter``` and start typing , the autocomplete works but when I type ```key``` and press ```Enter``` and start typing , the autocomplete won't popup . ```{Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map((each,index) => {
      return <View  key={index} style={{ backgroundColor : 'red' }} ></View>;
      })} ```

Comment: can you [check if you have `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters` set to `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65880666/11107541)?

Comment: I tried ```true``` and ```false``` with this option and none of em worked .